# Adjusting weight updates in a generative model

Tags: machine-learning, generative-models

Suppose I am training a generative model *G* to produce vectors *z* in *R^d*, where *d* is fixed. The objective of *G* is to produce realistic vectors, which I am calling the *"reality objective"*. Further suppose that *G* produces *"plausible*" and *"implausible"* vectors during training and I have a second model *E*, which can tell whether the vector is plausible or not. *E* is trained separately under what I call the *"plausibility obective"*. In this context, plausibility is a weaker constraint than being realistic, i.e. everything that is realistic is plausible, but not everything that is plausible is realistic. Moreover, training *E* is far easier than training *G*.

How do I best combine *G* and *E* ? Can I let *E* output a score *r* which I then use to reweight the weight update for *G* toward more plausible outputs? The issue is that, sometimes, weight updates through backprop will lead *G* into regions of the space *R^d* which are implausible. This is easier to tell for *E* than for *G*.

I would like to prevent *G* from venturing into implausible space through the involvement of *E*. Is there a name to what I am trying to do and do you know of a feasible method?

Comment: You should look into Generative Adversarial Networks. They give you a way on how to incorporate a discriminator (deciding between realistic/unrealistic, plausible/implausible..) into your loss. As you noticed, your generative model will go through regions of producing terrible samples. GANs are known to be finicky creatures.

Comment: What if my generative model is a GAN, but it's learning in a space that has terrible samples sometimes? Is there a way I can "augment" the GAN with an evaluator that decides if the samples are good? Note that this criterion is different from what the discriminator would do. Am I making sense?

Comment: Do you mean that your data has some samples in them which are terrible themselves? So you basically need to avoid them, when learning the GAN? If this is the case, you probably need to encode some "expert" knowledge on what good samples are.

Comment: Not the data, but the space within which I am learning. The space is provided by variational autoencoders (VAEs), which suffer from the prior hole problem (some latent vectors are not reconstructed to valid outputs). I want to guide the GAN's optimisation s.t. it only considers latent vectors z which are valid. In other words, all my data are transformed into latent space, and learning as well as backprop for the GAN also occurs in latent space. I want to prevent gradient updates from venturing into regions of "implausible" vectors z of the VAE.

Comment: In this paper (https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/hash/0496604c1d80f66fbeb963c12e570a26-Abstract.html), they are augmenting sampling from a VAE through a discriminator to address the prior hole problem. The discriminator learns to distiguish between samples from the prior and samples from the aggregate posterior and outputs a score: r(z). During test time sampling from the VAE, r(z) is used as a reweighting factor to adjust VAE-generated outputs to more plausible ones (i.e. ones that are not the result of the prior hole problem). I was wondering if I can reapply this idea to my setting.